# Using Select Alias in where clause

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I have a table `games`

```
+------------------+----+
|      title       | id |
+------------------+----+
| Need for Speed   |  1 |
| Far Cry          |  2 |
| Assassin's Creed |  3 |
+------------------+----+
```

and I have a table `games_played`

```
+-----------+---------+
| player_id | game_id |
+-----------+---------+
|         1 |       1 |
|         1 |       2 |
|         2 |       3 |
|         2 |       1 |
|         3 |       2 |
|         3 |       1 |
+-----------+---------+
```

What I need here is select all the games that player_id 1 haven't played and also the number of times the game was totally played.

```
+------------------+----+--------+--------+
|      title       | id |  count | played |
+------------------+----+--------+--------+
| Assassin's Creed |  3 |    1   |   f    |
+------------------+----+--------+--------+
```

Here is the query I wrote

```
select * from games, count("games_played.*"),
exists(select games_played.player_id from games_played where 
games_played.player_id = 1 and game_id = games.id) as played,
inner join games_played
on games_played.game_id = games.id
where played = false;
```

This is throwing and error column `played` does not exist.

Can someone help me here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with the query. `FROM` and column expression are misplaced, `"games_played.*"`  is not doing what it looks like, inner join instead of outer join, etc.

Try this one (I assume that `(id)` is the primary key of `games`):

```
select
    games.*, 
    count(games_played.*)
        as count,
    count(*) filter (where games_played.player_id = 1) > 0
        as played
from games
    left join games_played
    on games_played.game_id = games.id
group by 
    games.id
order by
    games.id ;
```

Test at **[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7805dcf6e3a7804674d8cf81acf1831d)**

Comment: Thanks for the query and also thanks for sharing https://dbfiddle.uk this, which I just came to know that something like this exists.

Comment: I have edited the question, what can I do if I just wanted to have just the games that user haven't played ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, using `having`.

```
select games.*, 
   count(games_played.*) as count
from games
   left join games_played
   on games_played.game_id = games.id
group by 
   games.id
having
   count(*) filter (where games_played.player_id = 1) = 0;
```